# Allow multiple users access to private S3 folder using IAM roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to do the following:

- Have a single bucket
- Have multiple users be able to add/read/access objects with a specific project folder prefix
- Not allow other users to access objects they don't belong to

So for example, if you have a project with id `1`, multiple users can create objects under it:

> user_1 created `1/image_1.jpg`
>
> user_2 read `1/image_1.jpg`
>
> user_2 created `1/image_2.jpg`

However, users who don't belong to the "project", can't:

> **NOT ALLOWED** user_3 read `1/image_1.jpg`

Everything I've found online revolves around each user having their own folder by creating an IAM role which only allows access to objects that are prefixed with the user's id. That approach creates *user folders*, I want *project folders*.

Comment: Do your users have work in your company and have IAM credentials, or are they just application users who access the application via the Internet?  In general, IAM Users should only be created for staff who are working with your AWS system. Also, how are the "projects" managed? Is there some application that determines what they are permitted to access?

Comment: No they don't. I was under the impression IAM roles are specifically for situations where you don't have regular IAM credentials The best way to describe this scenario is like a website with signup/login using Cognito and you can create shared photo albums. As for access, I have a database that keeps track of who is allowed to edit what, I'm just not sure what the best way to link that to S3 is. So far, looks like I'll have to upload to a node/express API that will then check permissions and upload the images itself but I was hoping to let users upload directly to S3 using IAM roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical architecture is:

- When an application wants to **display a private object**, or provide a link to a private object, it generates a [Pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).
- This pre-signed URL provides **time-limited access** to a private object.
- Users can use the link to view/download the object. For example, it might be used in an `<img>` tag to display a picture, or in a `<a>` tag to provide a link.
- When a user wants to **upload an object**, then can [Upload Objects Using Presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html). This can control where the object is uploaded, the type of file, maximum size, etc.

This way, the **application has full control** over which objects the user an upload/download, which gives much more fine-grained control than having to create IAM rules for every combination of user, project, folder, object, etc. The pre-signed URL can be used to directly access S3, but only to do what the application has authorized.

Comment: Got it, my main concern was the user finding a way to upload more images than they are allotted. I guess signed URLs with really quick expiration times are the path forward. Thanks.